# Deep copy an XML node in Saxon Java external function

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I'm writing a Java external function that is supposed to be called from an XSLT stylesheet. I intend to return a modified node passed to my function as a parameter. However, I cannot deep copy a node since I'm getting `The Saxon DOM cannot be updated`. (I think the exception is a bit misleading since I'm not trying to modify a Saxon node). So my question is: what's the best way to utilize external function input nodes in order to return a modified version of it (e.g. adding an additional text node as a child)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first reaction would be that manipulating XML node trees is much better done in XSLT than in Java, so calling extension functions in order to do node manipulation seems very strange. In particular, "adding an additional text node as a child" is what XSLT was designed to do, so it seems very odd to call Java to do it.

Any code you do write in Java to manipulate nodes is going to be dependent on the tree model used. From the error message, it sounds as if you're probably building the tree initially using Saxon's TinyTree model, and then wrapping the TinyTree nodes in a DOM wrapper for the benefit of your Java code. The DOM wrapper will give you a DOM interface for retrieval/navigation, but not for update, because the TinyTree is immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Michael. The case of adding a text node was rather just an oversimplified example. I need to run some complicated algorithms on a bunch of nodes and I believe in my case the much easier way is to use Java external function. So can you please suggest me a way how to make a mutable copy of a node or at least an immutable node that will be suitable for embedding into a programatically created one? Thanks!

Comment: Actually I don't even need to copy a node, I just need a way to attach a wrapped TinyTree node to a programatically created one, but obviously it fails since the former node belongs to another document.

Comment: Try `DOMWriter w = new DOMWriter(); w.setNode(programmaticallyCreatedNode); tinyTreeNode.copy(w, CopyOptions.ALL_NAMESPACES, 0)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the code snippets fails. As I need a bit more space for reply I would go into answer section

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the following code fails:

```
DOMWriter w = new DOMWriter(); 
w.setNode(programmaticallyCreatedNode); 
tinyTreeNode.copy(w, CopyOptions.ALL_NAMESPACES, 0);
```

with (I'm using Saxon 9.1.0.8)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMWriter.startElement(DOMWriter.java:103)
at net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyElementImpl.copy(TinyElementImpl.java:280)
...
```

I copied the node with:

```
DOMWriter w = new DOMWriter();
w.setNode(parentElementProgramaticallyCreated);
Element toCopy = ...;
((ElementOverNodeInfo)toCopy).getUnderlyingNodeInfo().copy(w, NodeInfo.ALL_NAMESPACES, false, 0);
```

Brief look at the code showed me that the NPE is because of not initialized namePool field in DOMWriter. Maybe I'm doing something completely wrong, but my intuition told me that copying a node should be somewhat simple.

Btw, I'm not tied to using DOM with Saxon, anything that would allow me receive a list of elements, read basic info from them (I was not able to quickly  figure out how to get a list of attributes with their values from TinyElementImpl) and construct/copy nodes will serve my purpose. Again, I'm doing some complicated logic with attribute values in Java and depending on the result return a rearranged XML tree. That would be really painful to do it in plain XSLT.

Comment: These are APIs that aren't really designed for external use so they may not be as robust as Saxon's public APIs; and you may well have to look at the code to diagnose NPEs. Probably what's missing is a call on w.setPipelineConfiguration(config.makePipelineConfiguration()), where you can get the Configuration config by applying NodeInfo.getConfiguration() to the TinyTree node.

Comment: If you do want to navigate the tinytree programmatically, you can, but it was designed for the convenience of the XPath engine, not for application programming. Generally the way you find your way around it is using NodeInfo.iterateAxis(), in this case using the attribute axis.